# How to retrieve the source code of an element in the "Elements" console using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the source code for a [website](https://boutiques.bouyguestelecom.fr/bouyguestelecom/fr/france/ile-de-france/paris/paris) using Python's BeautifulSoup library. However, the part of the source code that I obtained with BeautifulSoup is incomplete and does not include certain elements that I can see in the "Elements" console. Specifically, I am looking for elements that are visible in this picture:

[image].

How can I retrieve these elements from the console using Python?

```
url2="https://boutiques.bouyguestelecom.fr/bouyguestelecom/fr/france/ile-de-france/paris/paris"
response = requests.get(url2)  # Envoie une requête HTTP à l'URL et récupère la réponse
html_content = response.text
```

Tried this but does not get the result i wanted, I also tried selenium (webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

When your web browser requests a web page, it will parse the HTML into what we call the DOM. Then it runs the JavaScript on that page which can manipulate and change the DOM. The final result is what you see in the "Elements" tab of your browsers dev tools.

On the other hand, when you do `requests.get()` all you get is the raw HTML response. You do not execute any of the JavaScript. I recommend that you right click on the page and click View Page Source. This shows the exact same text that your python program gets.

In order to get the results after running the JavaScript for the site, you can use `selenium` instead of `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how did you try selenium (since you didn't share any code snippet) that didn't get you those elements. But you do get all those 24 search results.

You can try this way: **Selenium+Beautifulsoup**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://boutiques.bouyguestelecom.fr/bouyguestelecom/fr/france/ile-de-france/paris/paris"
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
search_results = soup.find('ul', {"id": "list-store"}).find_all('li', {"class": "item-magasin"})
print(len(search_results))
```

output:

```
24
```

You see, It returns all those 24 search results that are present under the `li` tags.

or using only **Selenium**:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://boutiques.bouyguestelecom.fr/bouyguestelecom/fr/france/ile-de-france/paris/paris"
driver.get(url)

search_results = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul[id="list-store"]').find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.item-magasin')
print(len(search_results))
```

output:

```
24
```